# jQuery.parseJSON returning null

Tags: jquery

I am getting JSON back from a web service. When I use `jQuery.parseJSON`, for some reason it is null. This is an example of the JSON (got by using `JSON.stringify(msg)`)

```
{"0":{"i":"1x 8351-3 & 2 x 8352-3","D":"Notes","V":"1x 8351-3 & 2 x 8352-3"},"1":{"i":"PC3","D":"Unit","V":"PC3"},"2":{"i":"PC3","D":"Unit","De":"Unit","V":"PC3"}}
var data = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
```

data is null? Am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/5VVqg/. Make sure the actual JSON you receive is valid: http://jsonlint.org/.

Comment: when i load you page i get [object Object] in alert, is that suppose to happen?

Comment: That's the default string representation of an object. It should demonstrate that the result is not `null`. It could also be that the JSON is already parsed. How you are you getting the data?

Comment: Probably one of these questions http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+parseJSON+returns+null will help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your `JSON` is like this (assuming you are fetching data from web sevice via getJSON)

```
 {"error":"Error KL005"}
```

Then you don't need to call the `parseJSON`. It is a well formed JSON object. You can simply parse thru it.

```
var response={"error":"Error KL005"};
alert(response.error);
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/6YHeB/2/

Use [JsonLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to check whether your expressions are valid JSON.

Comment: `var response={"error":"Error KL005"};` is not JSON nor a well formed JSON object. It's simply a JavaScript object.

Comment: @FelixKling : Showed in a variable to demonstrate how to access the properties (from my js fiddle example). Fixed it now

Comment: It's still confusing. The crucial part is that if OP uses `getJSON`, then the JSON is already parsed. But that has nothing to do with the structure of the JSON. If the response is not valid JSON, jQuery would not be able to parse it anyway.

Comment: @FelixKling: Yea. I mentioned that (assuming you are using getJSON to get data). OP provided the JSON result he has and it seems to be valid JSON. So we do not need to parse it again. That was my whole point as well.

Comment: I think you are confusing object literals with JSON. JSON is a data exchange format and by itself is just text. It has to be converted into the data structures of the language you are using, this means into JavaScript objcts/arrays here. Valid JSON does not mean it does not have to be parsed, it means it is "parse-able". Methods such as `$.getJSON` or setting the `dataType: 'json'` option for `$.ajax` do this automatically for you.

Comment: @FelixKling : Agreed. Does that mean that the provided JSON expression still needs parsing to access the data in that ?

Comment: As I said, that depends. If jQuery already parsed it for you, then you don't have to. But since we don't know how the OP gets the data, we cannot say for sure. Though it is likely that it is already parsed.